# Regex is working differently on Java than it should be according to regex101

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the following regex:

```
^Other: \[Hours\] ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) has played (([0-9]+) days)?(\.)?( )?(([0-9]+) hrs)?(\.)?( )?(([0-9]+) mins)?(\.)?$
```

This is the text being read:

```
Other: [Hours] Name1 has played 75 days 12 hrs 53 mins.
Other: [Hours] Name2 has played 102 days 9 hrs.
Other: [Hours] Name3 has played 4 hrs 32 mins.
Other: [Hours] Name4 has played 96 days 21 mins.
```

This is the code:

```java
    Pattern dhm = Pattern.compile("^Other: \\[Hours\\] ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) has played (([0-9]+) days)?(\\.)?( )?(([0-9]+) hrs)?(\\.)?( )?(([0-9]+) mins)?(\\.)?$");
    Matcher matcher = dhm.matcher("");

    Path path = Paths.get(fileName); 
    try (
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, ENCODING);
            LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(reader);
    ){
      String line = null;
      while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
        matcher.reset(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
          String name = matcher.group(1);
          String stringdays = matcher.group(3);
          String stringhours = matcher.group(7);
          int days = Integer.parseInt(stringdays);
          int hours = Integer.parseInt(stringhours);
          System.out.print(name + ": ");
          System.out.println(days * 24 + hours);
        } else {
            matcher.reset(line);
        }
      }      
    }    
    catch (IOException ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The only lines that actually end in an output are the ones sorted in the correct order (days -> hours -> minutes), so:

```
Name1: 1812
Name2: 2457
```

The rest, for some reason, don't actually get calculated.

Comment: The regex is working fine, your code aborts with a number format exception after successfully matching the third line.

Answer (score 0):

Groups related to `days` and `hours` may return `null` as they are optional, so you need to add null checks:

```
String stringdays = matcher.group(3);
String stringhours = matcher.group(7);
int days = null == stringdays ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(stringdays);
int hours = null == stringhours ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(stringhours);
```

Then the output is ok:

```
Name1: 1812
Name2: 2457
Name3: 4
Name4: 2304
```

You may want to extract this check into separate method and use `Optional`:

```
static int parseNullable(String intString) {
    return Integer.parseInt(Optional.ofNullable(intString).orElse("0"));
}

int days = parseNullable(stringdays);
int hours = parseNullable(stringhours);
```